# Visual Studio Load of Referenced DLLs

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, dll, reference

Sorry, but I'm not that familiar with Visual Studio...

I have a project in VS2010 that to build correctly, I've created References to DLLs that contain library methods used by the project.  Without the references I get build errors.

I can see the references in the Solution Explorer.
This is a plugin that compiles and now builds with no errors or warnings.

But when I run it to try to debug it, I see that it crashes when using an object that is defined in one of the referenced libraries.

When I look in the Modules window I can see that there are actually two copies of that dll which have loaded -- one located in the area where the main program is deployed and the other from the directory where my plugin is located.  I'm assuming this is a likely reason for why it is crashing.

After doing a build, a few of the dlls that are referenced in the project get copied over to the build debug directory.  The one causing a problem is one of those copied over, but it is the only one that appears to have been loaded from two places.  I don't know why some of the referenced dlls gets copied over and others don't.  And I don't know why only this one dll has been loaded from two locations.

I did a text search over all project files for the name of the dll to see if there were somehow multiple references in the project that would cause the dll to be loaded twice.

Any suggestions about how to fix this?

Comment: Is the source of the referenced library part of the solution that you are building ?

Comment: Check that the versions of the dll's are the exact same.

Comment: @Ram -- The dll where I have the problem is not mine.  It comes from a dll distributed with an app.

Comment: @Steve  When I look in the modules window I can see that the two dlls loaded are from different paths, but they have the same name and same version number.  The dlls are different though -- one is optimized and the other is not.